# Limit as $z$ approaches $0$ for $e^{1/z^4}$

Tags: limits, continuity, exponential-function

I want to work out if the limit as $z$ approaches $0$ for $e^{1/z^4}$ exists and if not then why. I worked out that the left and right sided limits both equal to +∞ so I thought that was enough to conclude that the limit therefore existed.

But when I checked the solutions it said that the limit did not exist, because you get different limits when you approach ($0,0$) along different rays, ($x,y$) = ($at,bt$) as $t$ $\rightarrow$ $0$.

I don't understand this though can anybody help explain? What does it mean by the rays? Like gradients?

**Edit** $z$ is a complex number

Comment: Whati s $z$? How did a 2-d plane come into play with different variables $(x,y)$ ?

Comment: ah sorry $z$ is a complex number so i'd say $z$ = $x + iy$

Comment: a ray is just a straight line in the complex plane that contains the zero, that is, a ray is a path of the form $\{rw:r\in\Bbb R\}$ for some fixed $w\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: so why does the limit change along different rays, wouldnt they all be zero as you approach zero?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think taking limits through rays is a good idea here. As $z$ approaches $0$ through the sequence $\{\frac 1 n\}$ the limit is $\infty$. If $z_n$ is  a 4-th root of $\frac 1 {2n\pi i}$ the the limit through this sequence is $1$ (and  $\{z_n\}$ does tend to $0$). Hence the limit  does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Try checking limits for $z_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and for $z_n=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2 \cdot n}$

**Edit:**
[You can also take a look at the plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot(exp(1%2Fz%5E4)))